Audio is Playing but not Showing in notification Android API 34
after updating my API to 34 , when i play Audio is playing but not be showing in Notification List . so i can not Stop the Audio even when i close the App, and i dont see any error in Logcat to see where error come . how to fix it when playing Audio to show notification when click icon in notification to stop Audio
i already added Service to manifest.xml

 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />




<service
            android:name=".services.AudioService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>  



this is my  Foreground.kt


 
class Foreground(val activity: Context) {

    private var iconNotification: Bitmap? = null
    private var notification: Notification? = null
    private var mNotificationManager: NotificationManager? = null

    @SuppressLint("LaunchActivityFromNotification")
    fun generateForegroundNotification(): Notification? {
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val broadCast = Intent(Constant.PAUSE)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            activity, 0, broadCast, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
        )
        iconNotification = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.resources, R.drawable.logo)
        if (mNotificationManager == null) {
            mNotificationManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            assert(mNotificationManager != null)
            mNotificationManager?.createNotificationChannelGroup(
                NotificationChannelGroup("chats_group", "Chats")
            )
            val notificationChannel =
                NotificationChannel("service_channel", "Service Notifications",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            notificationChannel.enableLights(false)
            notificationChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET
            mNotificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(activity, "service_channel")

        builder.setContentTitle(StringBuilder(activity.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).append(" is playing").toString())
            .setTicker(StringBuilder(activity.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).append("service is running").toString())
            .setContentText("Touch to stop") //                    , swipe down for more options.
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setWhen(0)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)

        if (iconNotification != null) {
            builder.setLargeIcon(
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    iconNotification!!, 128, 128, false
                )
            )
        }

        builder.color = activity.resources.getColor(R.color.blue)
        notification = builder.build()
//        }

        return notification
    }
} 




this is my MediaNotification.kt


 class MediaNotification(private val activity: Context) {

    companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "audio_service_channel"
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 101
    }

    private var notificationManager: NotificationManager? = null

    fun buildNotification(playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus) {
        // Create a MediaStyle notification
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(activity, CHANNEL_ID)

        // Pending intent for previous button click
        val prevIntent = MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
            activity, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS
        )

        // Pending intent for play/pause button click
        val playPauseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            activity, 0,
            Intent(activity, AudioService::class.java).setAction(ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE.toString()),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        // Pending intent for next button click
        val nextIntent = MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
            activity, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT
        )

        // Create notification
        val notification = builder.setContentTitle("Quran Audio")
            .setContentText("Playing audio")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_transparent)
            .setLargeIcon(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    activity.resources,
                    R.drawable.logo_transparent
                )
            )
            .setContentIntent(playPauseIntent)
            .setDeleteIntent(
                MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                    activity, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
                )
            )
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .addAction(R.drawable.logo_transparent, "Previous", prevIntent)
            .addAction(
                if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING)
                    R.drawable.logo_transparent else R.drawable.logo_transparent,
                if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING)
                    "Pause" else "Play",
                playPauseIntent
            )
            .addAction(R.drawable.logo_transparent, "Next", nextIntent)
            .setStyle(
                androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2) // Previous, Play/Pause, Next buttons
                    .setMediaSession(MediaSessionCompat(activity, "Audio").sessionToken)
            )
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build()

        notificationManager?.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }
}
  



```

this is my **AudioService.kt**




```

     
     
class AudioService : Service(), MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    private var startReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null
    private var pauseReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null

    class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        val service: AudioService
            get() = AudioService()
    }

    private var surah = 0
    private val TAG = "Audio Service"
    private var current = 0
    private var playList = ArrayList<String>()
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var audioManager: AudioManager? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return LocalBinder()
    }

    @SuppressLint("ForegroundServiceType")
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        intent?.let {
            surah = it.getIntExtra("SURAH", 0)
            current = it.getIntExtra("CURRENT", 0)
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            }
            playList = it.getStringArrayListExtra("LIST")!!
            if (mediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer()
            if (requestAudioFocus()) playAudio()
            else stopSelf()
        }

        startReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                intent?.let {
                    surah = it.getIntExtra("SURAH", 0)
                    current = it.getIntExtra("CURRENT", 0)
                    if (mediaPlayer == null)
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
                    playList = it.getStringArrayListExtra("LIST")!!
                    if (requestAudioFocus()) playAudio()
                    else stopSelf()

                    playList.forEach { i ->
                        Log.e("Receiver", i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        pauseReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                intent?.let {
                    mediaPlayer?.pause()
                    stopForeground(true)
                    stopSelf()
                }
            }
        }

        // Register the receivers with the Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            registerReceiver(startReceiver, IntentFilter("START_ACTION").apply { addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT) }, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            registerReceiver(pauseReceiver, IntentFilter("PAUSE_ACTION").apply { addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT) }, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
        }

        // These additional registerReceiver calls without the export flag might be redundant if START_ACTION and PAUSE_ACTION are the intended actions
        // registerReceiver(startReceiver, IntentFilter(PLAY))
        // registerReceiver(pauseReceiver, IntentFilter(PAUSE))

        startForeground(101, Foreground(this).generateForegroundNotification())

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    fun playAudio() {
        sendBroadcast(
            Intent(Constant.SURAH+surah)
                .putExtra("AYAT", current)
        )
        Log.e("Player", Constant.SURAH+surah)
        try {
            mediaPlayer?.reset()
            mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(playList[current]))
            mediaPlayer?.prepare()
            mediaPlayer?.start()
            mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
                current++
                if (playList.size>current) {
                    mediaPlayer?.reset()
                    mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(playList[current]))
                    mediaPlayer?.prepare()
                    mediaPlayer?.start()
                    sendBroadcast(
                        Intent(Constant.SURAH+surah)
                            .putExtra("AYAT", current)
                    )
                } else {
                    stopForeground(true)
                    stopSelf()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Service Error", "$e")
        }
        Log.e("Player", "Last")
    }

    private fun initMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnErrorListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnInfoListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.reset()

        mediaPlayer?.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    }

    private fun requestAudioFocus(): Boolean {
        audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        val result = audioManager!!.requestAudioFocus(
            this,
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN
        )
        return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED
    }

    private fun removeAudioFocus(): Boolean {
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
                audioManager?.abandonAudioFocus(this)
    }

    override fun onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion")
    }

    override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared")
    }

    override fun onError(mp: MediaPlayer?, what: Int, extra: Int): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "onError")
        return true
    }

    override fun onAudioFocusChange(focusChange: Int) {
        when (focusChange) {
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN -> {
                if (mediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer() else if (!mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer!!.start()
                mediaPlayer!!.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f)
            }
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS -> {
                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer!!.stop()
                mediaPlayer!!.release()
                mediaPlayer = null
            }
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ->
                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer!!.pause()
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK ->
                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer!!.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f)
        }
    }

    override fun onSeekComplete(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSeekComplete")
    }

    override fun onInfo(mp: MediaPlayer?, what: Int, extra: Int): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "onInfo")
        return true
    }

    override fun onBufferingUpdate(mp: MediaPlayer?, percent: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        removeAudioFocus()
        unregisterReceiver(startReceiver)
        unregisterReceiver(pauseReceiver)
    }
}




and this is my  AudioService.kt

class AudioService : Service(), MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    private var startReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null
    private var pauseReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null

    class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        val service: AudioService
            get() = AudioService()
    }

    private var surah = 0
    private val TAG = "Audio Service"
    private var current = 0
    private var playList = ArrayList<String>()
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var audioManager: AudioManager? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return LocalBinder()
    }

    @SuppressLint("ForegroundServiceType")
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        intent?.let {
            surah = it.getIntExtra("SURAH", 0)
            current = it.getIntExtra("CURRENT", 0)
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            }
            playList = it.getStringArrayListExtra("LIST")!!
            if (mediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer()
            if (requestAudioFocus()) playAudio()
            else stopSelf()
        }

        startReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                intent?.let {
                    surah = it.getIntExtra("SURAH", 0)
                    current = it.getIntExtra("CURRENT", 0)
                    if (mediaPlayer == null)
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
                    playList = it.getStringArrayListExtra("LIST")!!
                    if (requestAudioFocus()) playAudio()
                    else stopSelf()

                    playList.forEach { i ->
                        Log.e("Receiver", i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        pauseReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                intent?.let {
                    mediaPlayer?.pause()
                    stopForeground(true)
                    stopSelf()
                }
            }
        }

        // Register the receivers with the Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            registerReceiver(startReceiver, IntentFilter("START_ACTION").apply { addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT) }, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            registerReceiver(pauseReceiver, IntentFilter("PAUSE_ACTION").apply { addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT) }, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
        }

        // These additional registerReceiver calls without the export flag might be redundant if START_ACTION and PAUSE_ACTION are the intended actions
        // registerReceiver(startReceiver, IntentFilter(PLAY))
        // registerReceiver(pauseReceiver, IntentFilter(PAUSE))

        startForeground(101, Foreground(this).generateForegroundNotification())

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    fun playAudio() {
        sendBroadcast(
            Intent(Constant.SURAH+surah)
                .putExtra("AYAT", current)
        )
        Log.e("Player", Constant.SURAH+surah)
        try {
            mediaPlayer?.reset()
            mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(playList[current]))
            mediaPlayer?.prepare()
            mediaPlayer?.start()
            mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
                current++
                if (playList.size>current) {
                    mediaPlayer?.reset()
                    mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(playList[current]))
                    mediaPlayer?.prepare()
                    mediaPlayer?.start()
                    sendBroadcast(
                        Intent(Constant.SURAH+surah)
                            .putExtra("AYAT", current)
                    )
                } else {
                    stopForeground(true)
                    stopSelf()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Service Error", "$e")
        }
        Log.e("Player", "Last")
    }

    private fun initMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnErrorListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnInfoListener(this)
        mediaPlayer?.reset()

        mediaPlayer?.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    }

    private fun requestAudioFocus(): Boolean {
        audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        val result = audioManager!!.requestAudioFocus(
            this,
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN
        )
        return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED
    }

    private fun removeAudioFocus(): Boolean {
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
                audioManager?.abandonAudioFocus(this)
    }

    override fun onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion")
    }

    override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared")
    }

    override fun onError(mp: MediaPlayer?, what: Int, extra: Int): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "onError")
        return true
    }

    override fun onAudioFocusChange(focusChange: Int) {
        when (focusChange) {
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN -> {
                if (mediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer() else if (!mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer!!.start()
                mediaPlayer!!.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f)
            }
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS -> {
                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer!!.stop()
                mediaPlayer!!.release()
                mediaPlayer = null
            }
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ->
                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer!!.pause()
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK ->
                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer!!.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f)
        }
    }

    override fun onSeekComplete(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSeekComplete")
    }

    override fun onInfo(mp: MediaPlayer?, what: Int, extra: Int): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "onInfo")
        return true
    }

    override fun onBufferingUpdate(mp: MediaPlayer?, percent: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        removeAudioFocus()
        unregisterReceiver(startReceiver)
        unregisterReceiver(pauseReceiver)
    }
}




can anyone Help please
i already search it on google but not find that help me to fix it,because when i try to click Audio it Playing without any error but only not showing on notification .

Remove all @SuppressLint and fix it properly. What you even need two notifications for?

@MartinZeitler i remove it but nothing hapens

Obviously, you would also have the fix the warnings, which you've previously suppressed. This often helps to bring the code into shape, before trying to fix it furthermore. One should only use these, when there's a good reason to do so.
